# Data being entered as NULL in database through Spring Application

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, post, sql-null

I am trying to enter data into my database, but some fields are being entered as NULL

Here is fields of my `Model` class on Spring

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String AdType;
private String AdTitle;
private String ImageUrl;
private String LandingUrl;
private String Placement;
private String Country;
private String DSP;
// .. getters and setters
```

React code that is sending the request:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const creative = {ad_title, image_url, landing_url, ad_type, placement, country, dsp}
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/creative/add", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body:JSON.stringify(creative)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("New creative added")
    })
}
```

The values of `placement`, `country`, and `DSP` are being entered correctly but the rest are being entered as `NULL`. I personally think it might be because of them having an '_' between their names.
[image]

Comment: **Need more information**. Can you share all the methods your request is going through on the Java side (controllers, services, repositories)? Also, can you share an example request that is sent from React to your API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this was by renaming the fields of my `Model` class in the application. I basically changed `AdType` to `ad_type` in order to match the column names in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mapping problem caused by the underscore. Try changing the attribute names of your model class to camelCase. Maybe that solves your problem.

So it looks somewhat like this: `AdType` -> `adType` and so on...

Comment: Nope it still doesn't work